MariaDB Creating a Trigger does not work
I have a MariaDB 10.6 Server on a Rhel linux and I want to create a trigger for a table. This is my code:
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER before_salary_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE salary_change DECIMAL(10, 2);
    
    -- Calculate the percentage change in salary
    SET salary_change = (NEW.salary - OLD.salary) / OLD.salary * 100;

    -- Check if the change is within the 10% threshold
    IF salary_change > 10 OR salary_change < -10 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Salary change exceeds 10% limit.';
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

When I run my code with the delimiter my terminal freeze and I have to interrupt it with ctrl+c. When I execute it without the delimiter I get this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Also I tried to copy this into a sql file and execute it from the OS. But I have the same problem.

Verify what is the current delimiter used from the terminal by using \s
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.15-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          3028472
Current database:       crm_gesti
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          less
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;   #########  --- > see here
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.6.15-MariaDB MariaDB package
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb3
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb3
UNIX socket:            /run/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 128 days 18 hours 17 min 22 sec

As per your code it works fine
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> CREATE TABLE Employee (
    ->   salary int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.013 sec)

MariaDB [crm_gesti]>
MariaDB [crm_gesti]>
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> DELIMITER //
MariaDB [crm_gesti]> CREATE TRIGGER before_salary_update
    -> BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE salary_change DECIMAL(10, 2);
    ->
    ->     -- Calculate the percentage change in salary
    ->     SET salary_change = (NEW.salary - OLD.salary) / OLD.salary * 100;
    ->
    ->     -- Check if the change is within the 10% threshold
    ->     IF salary_change > 10 OR salary_change < -10 THEN
    ->         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    ->         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Salary change exceeds 10% limit.';
    ->     END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.182 sec)

MariaDB [crm_gesti]> DELIMITER ;

